# when i try to redirect after login i get 404 not found from a url i'm not even calling

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, redirect

I login successfully but after redirection i get a 404 error in consolelog and i didn't even mention this url in my code

[image]

this is my handlesubmit for the login :

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

if (formValid(this.state)) {
  console.log(`
    --SUBMITTING--
    
    Email: ${this.state.email}
    Password: ${this.state.password}
  `);
} else {
  console.error("FORM INVALID - DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE");
}

const { email, password } = this.state;
axios
  .post("http://localhost:4000/app/signin", { email, password })
  .then((res) => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(res));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    let decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    localStorage.setItem("decoded", decoded);
    console.log(decoded);
    if (res.status == 200) {
      this.props.history.push("/");
      console.log("Successfully Login");
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

};

Comment: What is in the code at whatever component is routed to `/`? I assume what you gave is not Home.js?

Comment: <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

Comment: I get redirected successfully but I always get that 404 error in console log and i don't know from where it came !

Comment: I meant the contents of Home.js . Something inside of there has to be trying to make the GET call to user that's returning the 404.

Comment: yees thank youu so much I didn't see it the first time thanks so much